# Zend Cache can not be included

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

Im trying to use Zend Cache.
As shown in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#quick-start

I used composer to load the framework:

```
{
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
    ],
    "require": {
    "zendframework/zend-cache": "2.*"
    }

}
```

My file structure is like this:
[image]

In the file `test.php`

I put the example code as shown in the docs:

```
<?php


use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;

// Via factory:
$cache = StorageFactory::factory(array(
    'adapter' => array(
        'name'    => 'apc',
        'options' => array('ttl' => 3600),
    ),
    'plugins' => array(
        'exception_handler' => array('throw_exceptions' => false),
    ),
));

// Alternately:
$cache  = StorageFactory::adapterFactory('apc', array('ttl' => 3600));
$plugin = StorageFactory::pluginFactory('exception_handler', array(
    'throw_exceptions' => false,
));
$cache->addPlugin($plugin);

// Or manually:
$cache  = new Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Apc();
$cache->getOptions()->setTtl(3600);

$plugin = new Zend\Cache\Storage\Plugin\ExceptionHandler();
$plugin->getOptions()->setThrowExceptions(false);
$cache->addPlugin($plugin);
```

But when I enter the page I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Cache\StorageFactory' not found in /var/www/libs/cache/vendor/test.php on line 7
```

I also tried to use:

```
include_once 'autoload.php';
```

But I got the same error.

Comment: Just checking, but you did run `composer install` after adding it to your composer file right? If so, maybe try a `composer du` to rebuild the autoload files.

Comment: Yes I installed all the files

Comment: You need the autoload, and don't create files in the vendor folder.

Comment: my code is break on this line pleasehelp me out I stuck before 10 day's  $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);